# Represent boolean OR opperator in non-boolean math notation

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to represent the boolean opperation OR in a regular formula, I am familiar with the boolean algebra notation, I came up with this `(A+B)/(A+B)`
this works for all binary values except if both `A=0 and B=0`
is there a simple alternative that also works if all inputs are `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that for AND, we could use the formula:
$$
A \land B \equiv A \times B
$$

Likewise for NOT, we could use the formula:
$$
\neg A \equiv 1 - A
$$

By using double negation and applying DeMorgan's Law, we can combine these together to get:
\begin{align*}
A \lor B &= \neg(\neg(A \lor B)) \\
&\equiv \neg(\neg A \land \neg B) \\
&\equiv 1-(1 - A)\times(1-B)\\
&\equiv \boxed{A + B - (A \times B)}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: excellent, thanks